# How to set the default chunk size for a custom PHP stream wrapper

Tags: php, php-stream-wrappers

When using a stream wrapper for PHP, the chunk size can be set on the client side with [`stream_set_chunk_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-chunk-size.php)

However, is there anyway to specify the chunk size from a custom stream wrapper implementation itself?

For example, an implementation of [`stream_write`](http://php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-write.php) receives the set of bytes, but the byte length is default 8192 bytes. I'm wondering if it's possible to change that default byte length.

Comment: stream_set_chunk_size(yoursocket, 1234);

Comment: @mwweb thanks, but I'm wanting to set the default chunk size from the stream wrapper implementation, not from the client instantiation.